# Install Matlab CLI interface on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: command-line, server, 16.04, matlab

Im having some problems to install Matlab through the CLI interface. I have mounted the .iso as root and then changed to my regular user account for installing the software.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Installation cannot proceed. You may either:
1. Set an X11 display, and restart the install process
2. Use the silent install feature by specifying the -mode silent option
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I use: printenv | grep DISPLAY 
there is no output

Also tried with ssh -Y or -X with no results
Also controlled the /etc/ssh/sshd_config that X11 is on forwarding

Anyone who encountered this and know how to solve it?

Thanks

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried installing the software with the `-mode silent` option? I'm not familiar with Matlab specifically, but for example, if to get that error message you ran `./setup`, try running `./setup -mode silent`

Comment: Hi

Not yet, I'm pretty sure that Matlab will provide a GUI interface even if I'm running the install in CLI. I'm not sure where the silent mode will put the installation path files, it has to be installed somewhere in the default path like /usr/local and not in my homefolder